# Do I have to declare my fruits flying into the EU?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, eu

I'm flying into the Schiphol. I know the rules regarding fruits, they can be found here: http://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontentnl/belastingdienst/prive/douane/wat_mag_niet_zomaar_in_uitvoeren/planten_bloemen/planten_bloemen_groenten_en_fruit_fytosanitaire_producten.

It says that 5 kg fruit can be taken if it is not a big risk for spreading dangerous organisms, it is for personal use etc. I think I'm fine on all points, except the first one which I cannot asses. I cannot find if I have to declare them, though. Do I? If so, how?

If it matters: I will be taking 3 mangos from China.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In another document, http://reizen-en-recreatie.infonu.nl/diversen/60730-douane-nederland-aangifte-doen.html , it says, emphasis mine:

> In de artikelen Douanebepalingen Nederland en Douanebepalingen Nederland, bijzondere goederen staat precies beschreven wat u Nederland mee in mag nemen **zonder aangifte te hoeven doen**.

Or in English,

> The articles "Customs regulations Netherlands" and "Customs regulations Netherlands, special goods" describe exactly what you are allowed to take with you into the Netherlands **without having to declare**.

The second of those documents has another description of those rules about fruit.

So a few fruits for personal use are allowed, and you don't have to declare them. They're treated exactly like everything else that you're allowed to just bring with you.