# How many fruits can I bring to European Union?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, europe, food-and-drink

Is there some general, definitive EU regulation about bringing fruits from outside of EU? My flight will be São Paulo, Brazil - Paris - Frankfurt - Katowice (Poland), but I'm more interested if there is a general rule.

I found some information on the internet but it's mostly vague, for example [this leaflet from France customs](http://www.douane.gouv.fr/Portals/0/fichiers/information/publication-douane/langues-etrangeres/banned-and-authorised-foodstuffs-entering-eu.pdf) says

> **banned**
>
> potatoes, soil, seeds
>
> **The following products are AUTHORISED importation based on certain conditions**
>
> **fruits**, vegetables, certain flowers
>
> They must meet all of the following conditions
>
> - be stored in personal luggage
> - be intended for personal consumption
> - not pose a health hazard
> - not be banned from importation
> - small quantities
>
> (...)
>
> The potential health hazard and risk of spreading harmful organisms varies depending on the country of origin and the type of plant.

There is already a question [Do I have to declare my fruits flying into the EU?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67444/do-i-have-to-declare-my-fruits-flying-into-the-eu), but it seems Netherlands-specific.

I'm planning to bring several typical Brazilian fruits like starfruit, atemoya, graviola and mangaba, everything for personal use.

Answer (score 2):

The French Customs website has [a complete list](http://www.douane.gouv.fr/articles/a11624-restrictions-phytosanitaires-applicables-aux-vegetaux-fruits-et-legumes-en-provenance-d-un-pays-tiers), but in French. I suspect it is the same list for the rest of the EU. You're allowed 5 pieces or 5 kg (whatever works best for you) of:

- Fresh vegetables and fruit, except citrus.
- Edible roots and rhizomes, without any soil on them.
- Barks/peels for human consumption, except citrus.

Comment: Thank you, that's clearer. So it seems that every country has different laws and everytime I fly to EU I may be treated differently?

Comment: Laws in the EU are unified. That's the main concept behind the EU.