# Carrying fruits into the EU?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, europe, eu

I don't know about current EU restrictions on bringing in fruits for personal use. I want to bring in some cashew apples and mangoes from the tropics (for consumption).

My questions are:

1. Does anyone know what restrictions currently exist?
2. Do I need a certificate of sanitation?
3. Do I need to declare it at customs?

A user suggested [How many fruits can I bring to European Union?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101051/how-many-fruits-can-i-bring-to-european-union)
that this would answer my question, but this was over 5 years ago! Current restrictions may not be the same.

Cheers

Comment: How much fruit in total and, for completeness, which country? See https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/carry/meat-dairy-animal/index_en.htm and related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101051/how-many-fruits-can-i-bring-to-european-union

Comment: Just about 5 in total,  to Germany.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many fruits can I bring to European Union?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101051/how-many-fruits-can-i-bring-to-european-union)

Comment: This was over 5 years ago,  and I don't know if the restrictions are the same.

Comment: German customs page: [Zoll online - Pflanzenschutz](https://www.zoll.de/DE/Privatpersonen/Reisen/Rueckkehr-aus-einem-Nicht-EU-Staat/Einschraenkungen/Tiere-und-Pflanzen/Pflanzenschutz/pflanzenschutz_node.html) **Exceptions** *The following fruits are exempt from the aforementioned phytosanitary regulations and you do not need a phytosanitary certificate for them: pineapple, coconut, durio, banana, dates.*

Comment: where are you travelling from?

Comment: 5 in total, including cashews?